# How add custom toolbar button to ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular

Tags: angular, button, ckeditor, toolbar

I try methods for ckeditor 5 custom toolbar button in angular but all get errors, there are plugin like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@samhammer/ckeditor5-simple-button-plugin but i dont know how use it in ckeditor5-angular